# unfortunate project has stopped when i need to return news list from database with php web srvice

Tags: android

I need to return a news list with a php web service. However, when I run the project and click the button for go to activity last news it shows me this error.

What is the problem? How can I solve this problem?

**Last News Activity :**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_news);
        PostService postService=new PostService(this);
        postService.getPosts(new IPostService() {
            @Override
            public void OnPostRecived(List<Post> posts) {
                RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lastnews_recycle);
                NewsAdapter newsAdapter=new NewsAdapter(LastNewsActivity.this,posts);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(LastNewsActivity.this
                ,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Post Service :**

```
public class PostService {

private Context context;

public PostService(Context context){

    this.context = context;
}

public void getPosts(final IPostService postService){

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.1.2:8080/Test/GetPosts.php", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    List<Post> posts=new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=0 ; i<response.length();i++){

                        Post post=new Post();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                            post.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                            post.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                            post.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                            post.setContent(jsonObject.getString("content"));
                            post.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image_url"));
                            posts.add(post);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    postService.OnPostRecived(posts);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

}

**Post :**

```
public class Post {

private int id;
private String PostImageUrl;
private String Title;
private String Content;
private String Date;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return Content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    Content = content;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getImage() {
    return PostImageUrl;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    PostImageUrl = image;
}
```

}

**News Adapter :**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

private List<Post> posts;
private Context context;

public NewsAdapter( Context context,List<Post> posts ){

    this.posts = posts;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return new NewsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_news,parent,false));

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Post post=posts.get(position);
    holder.Title.setText(post.getTitle());
    holder.Content.setText(post.getContent());
    holder.Date.setText(post.getDate());
    Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImage()).into(holder.Image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return posts.size();
}

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView Image;
    private TextView Title;
    private TextView Content;
    private TextView Date;

    public NewsViewHolder(View itemview) {
        super(itemview);
        Image = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_news_image);
        Title = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_news_title);
        Content = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_news_content);
        Date = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_news_date);
    }
}
```

}

**Update**

show me this in Logcat :

> 05-04 05:01:16.031 2199-2199/com.learningandroid.a7learn.example.mr_enginner.newsproject E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   05-04 05:01:16.184 2199-2199/com.learningandroid.a7learn.example.mr_enginner.newsproject E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   05-04 05:01:16.320 2199-2233/com.learningandroid.a7learn.example.mr_enginner.newsproject D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xf3dc1800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xeec397b0

Comment: It was due to some unexpected/uncatched errors. Please check your logcat for debugging

Comment: @FernandoTan i update question